# How to ad .ini files to QuickMapServices

Tags: qgis, quickmapservices

I'm using QGIS Las Palmas with the QuickMapServices plugin and want to add additional data sources from the contributor pack so they are available from the menu. I downloaded the pack, but how do I add the ini files to QuickMapServices?

Comment: look at [quickmapservices_contrib](https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices_contrib) and [Adding data source](https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices/wiki/Adding-data-source)

Comment: If you follow `Web -> QuickMapServices -> Settings`, `More services` tab, `Get Contributed pack`, the files should be installed automatically in the right place.